# Send message to active tcp client from different function in c#

Tags: c#

i want to send message to all connected connection, the code is:

using NetCoreServer

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new ChatServer(context, IPAddress.Any, Port);
        server.Start();
        server.MulticastText("Send text to client");
    }

    public static void TimedBroadcast(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // i want to send broadcast message to connected client within this function to Main() function
        server.MulticastText("Send broadcast status to client with cron task");
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you know about variable scope? Do you know why this code won't compile?

Comment: no im not, new with c#, so i need suggestion how to make it work correctly :)

Comment: If you comment out the whole of the TimedBroadcast method, and run the app, does it quit immediately after calling MulticastText?

Comment: No, everything inside Main() is working fine.

trying to define **server** to block level scope like: **static ChatServer server**;
got this message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is some mechanism somewhere that prevents the app from exiting as soon as MulticastText is over and done, you just need to lift your `server` to a scope where both methods can access it:

```
class Program
{
    private static ChatServer _server = new ChatServer(context, IPAddress.Any, Port); //not sure where context, and Port come from

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _server.Start();
        _server.MulticastText("Send text to client");
    }

    static void TimedBroadcast(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // i want to send broadcast message to connected client within this function to Main() function
        _server.MulticastText("Send broadcast status to client with cron task");
    }
}
```

You also said in comments:

> trying to define server to block level scope like: static ChatServer server; got this message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Note that just because you make a variable declaration at class level/just because it's static doesn't mean it automatically becomes filled with an instance of an object so you probably lifted the declaration but then didn't anywhere have a `server = new ChatServer(...)` line to actually fill it with an instance of anything

Comment: thanks, now it work like i wish, so i have to move all needed variable to block level scope.

Comment: Doesn't have to be all of them, but anything you want to access in multiple different methods, yes - you either pass it into the method or make it in a scope where the method can access it